# missing writing values in json format

Tags: python, json, graphite

I am missing a last value of while trying to request data in json format from graphite webapp. The following is from render/views.py in the graphite web app. I am trying to use the threshold function to get constant data. How would i force graphite webapp to output two points in json format when using constantLine/ threshold function.

For raw format:

```
if format == 'raw':
      response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/plain')
      for series in data:
        response.write( "%s,%d,%d,%d|" % (series.name, series.start, series.end, series.step) )
        response.write( ','.join(map(str,series)) )
        response.write('\n')
```

My output is:

```
stats.gauges.server1.throughput,1387364850,1387364910,10|1190.0,1190.0,1190.0,1190.0,1190.0,1190.0
hello,1387364847,1387364907,60|45,45
```

However, for writing to json

```
if format == 'json':
      series_data = []
      for series in data:
        timestamps = range(int(series.start), int(series.end), int(series.step))
        datapoints = zip(series, timestamps)
        series_data.append( dict(target=series.name, datapoints=datapoints) )
```

My output is:

```
[{"target": "stats.gauges.server1.throughput", "datapoints": [[1190.0, 1387364980], [1190.0, 1387364990], [1190.0, 1387365000], [1190.0, 1387365010], [1190.0, 1387365020], [1190.0, 1387365030]]}, {"target": "hello", "datapoints": [[45, 1387364979]]}]
```

Ideally i would want it:

```
[{"target": "stats.gauges.server1.throughput", "datapoints": [[1190.0, 1387364980], [1190.0, 1387364990], [1190.0, 1387365000], [1190.0, 1387365010], [1190.0, 1387365020], [1190.0, 1387365030]]}, {"target": "hello", "datapoints": [[45, 1387364979], [45, 1387365030 ]]}]
```

I guess bug is here:

```
def constantLine(requestContext, value):
  """
  Takes a float F.

  Draws a horizontal line at value F across the graph.

  Example:

  .. code-block:: none

    &target=constantLine(123.456)

  """
  start = timestamp( requestContext["startTime"] )
  end = timestamp( requestContext["endTime"])
  #step = int((end - start) / 1)
  step = 5000
  series = TimeSeries(str(value), start, end, step, [value])
  return [series]
```

Comment: I think it's due to question formatting but output and ideal looks the same?

Comment: In the ideally, for the target hello, there are two data points.. while the current output has just one data point.

Comment: I think you'll need to show us the original data. I can't work out where the values are supposed to be coming from.

Comment: Hi Daniel, The function i showed is part of graphite, a a time series database. here, a function called constant line gives the data by using graphite.com/render?target=constantLine(value)&from=-2mins&until=now; The source code for constantLine function is

Answer (score 0):

Graphite only gives a single value for constantLine function or the threshold function. Consider that we use graphite only for querying the values in json and use a third party charting tool such as D3, Rickshaw or Highcharts, we would then land across the problem where we have just one value to plot.  In that case, we need to modify the constantLine function as follows:

```
start = timestamp( requestContext["startTime"] )
  end = timestamp( requestContext["endTime"])
  #step = (end -start -1)/1.0
  step = 10
  val_tmp = [value] * int((end-start))
  series = TimeSeries(str(value), start, end, step,val_tmp)
  return [series]
```

If using Django 1.6 , do not forget to change the import functions as given [here] (https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/commit/fc3f018544c19b90cc63797d18970a4cc27ef2ad#diff-e383725a971fca0685db19bfe7c65b32)

Hope this helps someone.